# Apparatus to measure one ampere

Tags: electric-current, measurements, units, history

The following definition of the Ampere was codified in 1948 at the 9th CGPM (Conference Général des Poids et Mésures)

The ampere is that constant current which, if maintained in two straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible circular cross section, and placed 1 meter apart in vacuum, would produce between these conductors a force equal to 2E-7 newton per meter of length. (CIPM (1946), Resolution 2 approved by the 9th CGPM, 1948).

My questions: How can one calibrate an ammeter according to this definition?

Did people actually build the above apparatus (two straight parallel conductors of infinite length...)? Any pictures/descriptions of such an apparatus?

Comment: In the US I would probably look to NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology)